# Windows Phone 7 Beta: ProgressBar.IsIndeterminate="True" breaks my JSON calls

Tags: progress-bar, windows-phone-7

This is the weirdest thing I've seen in a long time...
I have a simple application that makes some JSON calls to a server and processes the results, this takes a little while so I was planning to add a progress bar to indicate that something is happening.
This all works fine if I leave IsIndeterminate="False" however when I set it to True my JSON calls fail with
"The remote server returned an error: NotFound." {System.Net.WebException}
Anybody got any ideas what might cause this? I'm wondering if it could be a bug in the Beta tools?

Comment: I don't know anything about Windows Phone 7 development, but are you sure you're supposed to be passing your booleans as strings? I get a queasy feeling when I see `true` and `false` with quotes around them.

Comment: It's XAML so that is the correct format. I agreee it looks weird though

Comment: That is truly bizarre. Have you reproduced it in a simple project that just includes a JSON call and a progress bar?
I've had several weird issues that I've been unable to reproduce in a simple project, but still happen in my main project. :(

Comment: Hmm, I think I might have figured this out. I think my virus checker was getting in the way of my JSON calls (which cause a read/write to a MySQL DB). I think the behaviour I was seeing just happened to coincide with my testing of the progressbar. The odd thing is I tested switching true/false at least 5 times and I got consistent results. Will leave it a copule of days to confirm this has fixed it but it looks good so far...

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using the public release of the tools. In which case the indeterminate progress bar implementation has been found to use *huge* quantities of processor time. This is probably killing your networking.

I hope they will fix this for the proper release.

Comment: You can find an alternative "high performance" version at http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/08/performanceprogressbar/

Comment: I use the Jeff Wilcox code for ALL my apps, as it is ridiculous how much the progress bar chews resources